# React fullCalendar - Interaction not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

Here I am trying to use FullCalendar on a React project, I need to be able to create events per click. So I followed part of the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/react?file=/src/DemoApp.jsx

The calendar is displayed, I use the api to modify the current day, so I have things that work. But, I can't interact with it. I installed fullCalendar/interaction and specified the plugin in the component, but nothing happens at select & dateclick...
I put the part of my code, would you have an idea ? :/

Thanks a lot

```
import React, {useEffect, useState, useRef} from 'react'
import DayPicker from 'react-day-picker';
import MomentLocaleUtils from 'react-day-picker/moment';
import 'moment/locale/fr';

import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

const RoomsCalendars = ({match}) => {

    const {id} = match.params

    const [selectedDay, setSelectedDay] = useState()

    useEffect(() => {
        setSelectedDay(new Date())
    }, [])
    
    const calendarRef = useRef(null)

    const  handleDayClick = day => {
        setSelectedDay(day);
        let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi()
        calendarApi.gotoDate(day)
    }

    const handleTodayClick = day => {
        setSelectedDay(day)
        let calendarApi = calendarRef.current.getApi()
        calendarApi.gotoDate(day)
    }

    return(
        <>
            <h1>Salle {id}</h1>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="lg-3 md-4 sm-12">
                    <div className="card">
                        <DayPicker 
                            localeUtils={MomentLocaleUtils}
                            locale="fr"
                            todayButton="Aujourd'hui"
                            onDayClick={handleDayClick}
                            selectedDays={selectedDay}
                            onTodayButtonClick={(day) => handleTodayClick(day)}
                            fixedWeeks 
                        />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="lg-9 md-8 sm-12">
                    <div className="card">
                            <FullCalendar
                                plugins={[timeGridPlugin, dayGridPlugin,interactionPlugin]}
                                initialView="dayGridMonth"
                                headerToolbar={{
                                    left:'prev,next',
                                    center:'title',
                                    right:'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
                                }}
                                ref={calendarRef}
                                locale="fr"
                                slotMinTime="07:00:00"
                                slotMaxTime="20:00:00"
                                height={700}
                                editable={true}
                                selectable={true}
                                selectMirror={true}
                                dayMaxEvents={true}
                                select={console.log('select')} //NOT WORKING HERE
                                dateClick={console.log('dateclick')} //SAME
                            />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default RoomsCalendars
```

Comment: From what I can see in the "Callbacks" section at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react, you might have to specify a separate function as the option for each event - e.g.  `select={console.log('select')}` would need to be `select={this.logSelection}` and then have another function `logSelection = (arg) => {
    console.log("select");
  }` elsewhere in your component. The examples don't show how / if you can put executable code directly into the option configuration. At the very least you'd have to put it into an anonymous callback block I'd expect, just like regular JS.

Comment: Indeed I simplified for the example, but I already tried something like this: ```select={() => logSection}``` by doing the console log in ```const logSection = () => { console.log('select') } ``` but it doesn't work either :/

Comment: have you tried using it like the examples? e.g. `select={logSection}`

Comment: I found... fullcalendar/core was installed in version 5.2.0, and fullcalendar/interaction was in 5.3.0... I just did a core version upgrade

Answer (score 3):

try this

npm i @fullcalendar/interaction

Answer (score -1):

I hade the exact same problem, try eventClick method

```
eventClick = {(args) => handleDateClick(args)}
    select={console.log('select')} //NOT WORKING HERE
    dateClick={console.log('dateclick')} //SAME

const handleDateClick = (arg) => {
        console.log(arg);
    }
```